# Proguard rules for Jetpack GameActivity

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-gameactivity

I'm trying to use [Jetpack GameActivity](https://developer.android.com/games/agdk/game-activity) in my project, but I encounter a strange issue with Proguard. My project has 2 modules, `app` and `my-lib`:

- `my-lib` module has `MyActivity` which extends `GameActivity`:

  api 'androidx.games:games-activity:1.2.1'
- `app` module has `MainActivity` which extends `MyActivity` from `my-lib` module

  implementation project(":my-lib")

When I built my project in Release build and had Proguard enabled, I got a native crash:

- `Abort message: 'Unable to find method setWindowFlags'`

=> I tried inspecting `GameActivity` class from my APK, `setWindowFlags` method didn't exist at all, which means Proguard has removed it, that's why the native part of the GameActivity library couldn't find the method and it threw an error.

Then, I tried to fix it, by adding Proguard rule like this:

- `-keep, includedescriptorclasses class com.google.androidgamesdk.GameActivity { *; }`

But unfortunately, I got another native crash:

- `Abort message: 'Unable to find field left'`

=> Why does this happen? I tried inspecting the APK again, but have no idea why

Anyway, how can I deal with this situation? Does Jetpack GameActivty need to add Proguard rules to keep methods that will be used by the native part?

Answer (score 2):

There is a know issue in version 1.2.1 and before: the java functions called by native code only were stripped out by proguard for the release build. Version 1.2.2-alpha01 has fixed that and a few other important potential issues, including the static library release in the AAR. To use the 1.2.2-alpha01+:

1. Add [the latest version](https://d.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/games) to the dependency: 1.2.2-alpha01+
2. Use C/C++ static lib release in the AAR.
   add the following or something similar to your project's existing CMakeLists.txt

   ```
   find_package(game-activity REQUIRED CONFIG)
      add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED sth.cpp) #<=== this is your own.
   target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} game-activity::game-activity_static
   # optional: does not hurt to add it; refer to the official doc for update.
   set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS
    "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} -u \
    Java_com_google_androidgamesdk_GameActivity_initializeNativeCode")
   ```
3. If want to use the source code directly(not recommended), do something similar to this:

   ```
   # Find GameActivity sources to build.
   find_package(game-activity REQUIRED CONFIG)

   get_target_property(GAME_ACTIVITY_INCLUDE_PATH
       game-activity::game-activity
       INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
   string(REPLACE "include" "" GAME_ACTIVITY_SRCS ${GAME_ACTIVITY_INCLUDE_PATH})
   file(GLOB_RECURSE GAME_ACTIVITY_SRCS
       ${GAME_ACTIVITY_INCLUDE_PATH}/*.c*)
   add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED
       sth.cpp.   #<== this is your own file
       ${GAME_ACTIVITY_SRCS})
   target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
    android log
    game-activity::game-activity
    # other libs
    )
   ```

   Note: it is still just 3 source files now, and you can unzip [the latest AAR](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html#androidx.games:games-activity:1.2.2-alpha01) and list them explicitly like:

   ```
   add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED
       sth.cpp.   #<== this is your own file
       ${GAME_ACTIVITY_INCLUDE_PATH}/game-activity/GameActivity.cpp
       ${GAME_ACTIVITY_INCLUDE_PATH}/game-activity/native_app_glue/android_native_app_glue.c
       ${GAME_ACTIVITY_INCLUDE_PATH}/game-text-input/gametextinput.cpp)
   ```

   The `glob` way might be better for future compatibility reasons; but it is not cmake recommended way to do things.
4. Handle the the "back" button press to exit app either from Kotlin/Java side(handle `KEYCODE_BACK` in `onKeyDown()`) or native code (`AKEYCODE_BACK` in input key event processing).

Referring to [the documentation page](https://d.android.com/games/agdk/game-activity) and probably the list above, you should be able to get your project going. The simple fact is this: all of the C/C++ things are inside AAR, under the `prefab` sub-directory, you even can copy it out and directly put into your own source tree. [This Pull Request](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Samples/pull/549) might help (but not totally sure).

If you see something or like some new things, please [create a bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=897320&template=1456805).

Comment: Using `1.2.2`, are you able to read the axis X value of any joystick? My understanding is that all versions *after* `1.1.0` are in fact broken. Bug report [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/264177787).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues as you and I solved this by adding the following line to my proguard-rules.pro file:

-keep class com.google.androidgamesdk.** { *; }

Of course then I had other proguard related errors so I had to add these
additional lines:

`-keep class androidx.core.graphics.Insets { *; }`

`-keep class androidx.core.view.** { *; }`

`-keep class org.fmod.** { *; }`

Of course you will have different errors in your build, but hopefully this will help you.

Comment: thanks, I reported the issue to Google here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/246669088
they applied the fix in the latest version of GameActivity, I checked the latest GameActivity AAR content yesterday, proguard rules were added, but I don't test the latest version yet.

Comment: yeah, it is fixed now with version 1.2.2-alpha01.  For production usage, highly recommend app to use/update to this version and above: input event process limitation has been removed.

Comment: @Gerry I highly recommend to stick with `1.1.0` until [issue 264177787](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/264177787) is fixed. I spent a week trying to integrate `1.2.x` just to realize that not even the `AGDK` samples will run properly when updated.

Comment: @I33t the issue is real (the data structures are out of sync). Next version should fix it.  If you are not using the game-controller, updating is kind of necessary: the input event fix is kind of important.